# How to consume/read messages from KAFKA topic with filter condition

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a topic with different messages. But I need to consume only certain messages irrespective of the order in which message published. I need to apply data filter condition on specific field/attribute of the message. like file-name element of the JSON message is "XXXX.txt". Simply say consume message with where condition like traditional DB.

Comment: check this http://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#filter-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Predicate-

Comment: `kafka-streams` is a Java library... Are you still [using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57681875/getting-serialization-error-when-publish-message-to-kafka-topic)?

Comment: Yes..I need to use C# client.

Comment: Then your only option would be to subscribe and poll like normal. Afterwards, deserialize each record, and perform a simple if statement on your search criteria... Kafka Streams or KSQL do exactly that, as well

Comment: Use Reactive Kafka and use a filter.

Answer (score 3):

> .I need to use C# client

Then your only option would be to subscribe and poll like normal, adding an if statement for your condition

Borrowing snippet from the [Confluent consumer example](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/Consumer/Program.cs)

```
 // TODO: build consumer that reads string messages 
consumer.Subscribe(topics);
... 
while (true) {
    var consumeResult = consumer.Consume(cancellationToken);
    string value = consumeResult.Value;

    // TODO: parse string value to JSON object using your favorite JSON library 
    // Add your condition 
    if (jsonObj["file-name"].Equals("XXXX.txt"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Received message at {consumeResult.TopicPartitionOffset}: {value}");
    }
```

Regarding the JSON parser, you can either make a Dictionary or a strongly typed class, but this example assumes a dictionary. [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

> irrespective of the order in which message published.

As with any consumer, order is guaranteed within a partition